# Iphone - cellForRowAtIndexPath behaving weirdly when scrolling down and up

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll

I would like to get a TableView with different elements on the accessoryView, depending on the section. Everything works fine, but when I scroll down to section 2 and then scroll up again to section 0, the rows in section 0 have switchers. Could you please help me finding out what I'm doing wrong?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSInteger sectionIndex = [indexPath section];
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
NSDictionary *dictionary;
NSArray *array;
NSString *cellValue;
UISwitch *switchView;

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

switch (sectionIndex) {
    case 0:
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        break;
    case 2:
        switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        cell.accessoryView = switchView;
        [switchView setOn:NO animated:NO];
        [switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [switchView release];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

dictionary = [searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"advancedSearch"];
cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dequeuing your table cells (cf. `-[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:]`), which means that you are receiving table views that have already been allocated and possibly pre-populated with stale data. In `case 0:` and `case 1:` of your switch statement, you should add the following line:

```
cell.accessoryView = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different cell identifiers for different cells.
Something like:

```
NSString *CellIdentifier;
switch ([indexPath row]) {
   case 0: CellIdentifier = @"cell0";
           break;
   case 1: CellIdentifier = @"cell1";
           break;
   default: CellIdentifier = @"cell";
           break;
}
```

Otherwise Xcode thinks that all your cells have the same look and tries to reuse them while you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier you must use different identifiers for different cells because you reuse them.