# iOS how to name cell IDs?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am confronted with the same issue as this post [Iphone - cellForRowAtIndexPath behaving weirdly when scrolling down and up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742753/iphone-cellforrowatindexpath-behaving-weirdly-when-scrolling-down-and-up). I am confused how I should be using different cell IDs for different cells. I have a variety of cells:

- cells with switches
- cells with checkmarks
- groups of cells such that only one is checkmarked
- cells that change text after tapping them
- cells with indicators
- cells with no accessory type

Should I be using a different cell ID for each of these different types of cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use different reuse identifiers for each different type of cell.  That would make it so you won't have to do things like take a checkmark cell and change it to a switch cell.  You'll dequeue each type of cell and get back what you expect.  Does that make sense?